# creating a stored procedure from a recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'd like to create a mssql stored procedure to run a query like the following:

`SELECT thingID
FROM things
WHERE thingParentID = #arguments.id#`

recursively, accumulating `thingID`s in a list which is then returned by the stored procedure.

Does anyone know of a example like this that they can link to? or some documentation that might help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to create a procedure for that. All you need is to take a look on Recursive CTE

Comment: rtce are sweet thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work on SQL Server 2005 and up.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Ancestors (@thingID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT thingID, 1 [Level]
        FROM dbo.things
        WHERE thingParentID = @thingID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT p.thingID, [Level] + 1 [Level]
        FROM CTE c
        JOIN dbo.things p
            ON p.thingParentID = c.thingID
    )
    SELECT thingID, [Level]
    FROM CTE

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAncestors (@thingID int)
AS
    SELECT thingID, [Level]
    FROM dbo.Ancestors(@thingID)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! if someone has the chance to help me figure out how to provide multiple `thingID`s then that'd be helpful too.